# How to use Task Parallel Iibrary with ADO .NET data access

Tags: ado.net, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I'm trying to optimise ADO .NET (.Net 4.5) data access with Task parallel library (.Net 4.5), For an example when selecting 1000,000,000 records from a database how can we use the machine multicore processor effectively with Task parallel library. If anyone has found use full sources to get some idea please post :)

Comment: Client-side processing is usually the wrong place to solve data access problems.

Comment: yeagh that's right. But the data access happens on Server side and data is delivered to Clients through WCF services.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. WHY do you want to process the data on the client instead of the server side? No matter what you do, no matter the technology, performance will suffer

Comment: On server side. but using PLINQ with multicore processor we can access those recoreds with minimum time right?. Rather than operating in a one thread the task will execute on multiple cores parallely. PLINQ has extension methords for that but I want to get this done onely using Task Parallel Library and ADO .NET ( not using  LINQ)

Comment: Chances are that the client only has one single network line. Meaning, the DB server might do in-memory parallel processing, and the client might do in-memory parallel processing, but inbetween, the DB result set has to travel from server to client over a single line, i.e. in a serial fashion. PLINQ cannot change that fact. Thus let the DBMS prepare the smallest possible set of data that the client actually needs; read that data serially on the client (there's no other way AFAIK); and in a last step, do parallel processing with in-memory objects (no ADO.NET involved), if still needed.

Answer (score 4):

The following applies to all DB access technologies, not just ADO.NET.

Client-side processing is usually the wrong place to solve data access problems. You can achieve several orders of magnitude improvement in performance by optimizing your schema, create proper indexes and writing proper SQL queries.

Why transfer 1M records to a client for processing, over a limited network connection with significant latency, when a proper query could return the 2-3 records that matter?

RDBMS systems are designed to take advantage of available processors, RAM and disk arrays to perform queries as fast as possible. DB servers typically have far larger amounts of RAM and faster disk arrays than client machines.

What type of processing are you trying to do? Are you perhaps trying to analyze transactional data? In this case you should first extract the data to a reporting, or better yet, an OLAP database. A star schema with proper indexes and precalculated analytics can be 1000x times faster than an OLTP schema for analysis.

Improved SQL coding can also result in 10x-50x times improvement or more. A typical mistake by programmers not accustomed to SQL is to use cursors instead of set operations to process data. This usually leads to horrendous performance degradation, in the order of 50x times and worse.

Pulling all data to the client to process them row-by-row is even worse. This is essentially the same as using cursors, only the data has to travel over the wire and processing will have to use the client's often limited memory.

The only place where asynchronous processing offers any advantage, is when you want to fire off a long operation and execute code when processing finishes. ADO.NET already provides [asynchronous operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20.aspx) using the APM model (BeginExecute/EndExecute). You can use TPL to wrap this in a task to simplify programming but you won't get any performance improvements.

It could be that your problem is not suited to database processing at all. If your algorithm requires that you scan the entire dataset multiple times, it would be better to extract all the data to a suitable file format in one go, and transfer it to another machine for processing.

Comment: Actully what I'm trying to accomplish is, something like asparallel in Linq. I want to implement same functionality in ADO .NET using Task parallel library

Comment: PLINQ can handle any IEnumerable, the point is that it's the wrong thing to do. A database can do SELECTs much faster than the client, and it DOES uses parallel processing. What are you trying to do? What is the ACTUAL PROBLEM? PLINQ/TPL is the answer (as in 42), what is the  QUESTION?

Comment: Assume I have 15 years experience in data warehouses, OLAP and I have occasionally increased processing speeds 50 times by using SQL instead of client processing and please describe the business problem you are trying to solve, not the techniques

Comment: Thanks for your comment Panagiotis :). We have a Employee data table and we need to get a set of employees ( the filter parameter may be "AGE" ), the data accesssed through a web service and we use LINQ to SQL and asparallel extension methord when accessing data. But still it's kind a slow, we though of using ADO .NET insted of LINQ to optimise the process along with Task Parallel Library to execute it in parallel. I'm not sure whether this is possible

Comment: So are you trying to create a report, analyze the data or return a single employee object? Multiple objects per call? How many? Anyway, you probably made the request slower by adding AsParallel(). AsParallel() works on objects which means that the results of the L2S statement up to this point were pulled to the client and converted to objects, before passing to the rest of the LINQ query. You probably cloned your entire employee data table to the client by accident. Still, a bad L2S query will translate to a bad SQL query. How many rows should the service return for each query?